# Batch Files third "If NOT" statement not reached

Tags: file, batch-file, if-statement

Hello stackoverflow community,

I am writing a batch file to do some automatic computer maintenance and have included several antivirus applications. For some reason, the third "if not" statement is never reached.

```
:AV
REM MSE
if not '%MSE%'=='' (
Echo Scanning for viruses using Microsoft Security Essentials.
Echo.
%MSE% -Scan -ScanType 1
Echo.
GOTO Defrag
)

REM AVG
if not '%AVG%'=='' (
Echo Scanning for viruses using AVG.
Echo.
%AVG% /COMP /QT /TRASH
Echo.
GOTO Defrag
)

REM NOD32
if not '%NOD32%'==''(
Echo Scanning for viruses using NOD32.
Echo.
if '%NOD32%'=='' GOTO NOD32NotFound
%NOD32% /aind /auto /log-file="%userprofile%\Desktop\Scan_Results.txt"
Echo.
GOTO Defrag
)

REM If all else fails...
GOTO AVNotFound
```

Currently, there are three blocks of codes, one for each antivirus program. Each block of code is executed only when the variable %AVG% %MSE% or %NOD32% is not empty, meaning they point to a valid file. I assign the variables using the code:

```
if exist "%programfiles(x86)%\AVG\AVG2012\avgscana.exe" set AVG="%programfiles(x86)%\AVG\AVG2012\avgscana.exe"
```

All three blocks of code works perfectly, nothing is wrong with the coding. The problem is that whatever the third block is, it never executes. So in the current example, the blocks of code go in the order of MSE, AVG, and NOD32. NOD32's block of code does not execute because it's the third block. Conversely, if I cut and paste the blocks into another order with AVG's block of code being the third block, it would not execute.

Any ideas?

Any suggestions?

Edited for clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing a space in the line:

```
if not '%NOD32%'==''(
```

Try:

```
if not '%NOD32%'=='' (
```

When I tried the script this line caused a failure.  After changing the line, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Are the variables `%MSE%`, `%AVG%` or `%NOD32%` batch files?  If yes, you will need to invoke them using "call" instead (for example `call %AVG%`)

If you call a batch file from another, the first one will exit after executing the 2nd one, unless it is called with "call".

Comment: If a second Batch file is called from a first one with no `CALL` (nor `CMD /C`) command, the net result is equivalent to a "goto to another file" (if such thing would be possible). I called *Overlay* a Batch file invoked this way (instead of *Subroutine*).

Comment: The variables aren't batch files. They refer to: 
if exist "%programfiles%\Microsoft Security Client\Antimalware\MPCMDRUN.EXE" set MSE="%programfiles%\Microsoft Security Client\Antimalware\MPCMDRUN.EXE"

The script works perfectly, it's just the third block does not execute. So if the blocks of code go from MSE, AVG, NOD32, than NOD32's block of code would not execute since it's the third block. Conversely, if I cut and paste the blocks into a different order so AVG is the last block, AVG's block of code would not execute.

Comment: It appears that if you call a *.bat file from another *.bat file, the caller one will exit after the second (inner) finished. This saved me: the call has to be done with "call inner.bat" instead of "inner.bat".

Answer (score 0):

Do any of your `%AVG%`, `%NOD32%`, or `%MSE%` variables have brackets in them?  Could they be in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\` path?  A bracket will close the branch prematurely.

Place quotes around the executable part of the commands, for example:

```
"%MSE%" -Scan -ScanType 1
```

Comment: The variables could have brackets in them, but I coded the variables as strings with brackets already included: 
if exist "%programfiles(x86)%\AVG\AVG2012\avgscana.exe" set AVG="%programfiles(x86)%\AVG\AVG2012\avgscana.exe"

The individual blocks of code work just fine, it's just that the third block never executes. So if the blocks of code go from MSE, AVG, NOD32, than NOD32's block of code would not execute since it's the third block. Conversely, if I cut and paste the blocks into a different order so AVG is the last block, AVG's block of code would not execute.