# Making a batch DND assistant

Tags: batch-file

I don't know if any of you guys know anything about batch (I am sure someone does), but in regards to this post, I am trying to create a dumbed down DND Assist (something that you would tell you stats to and that would assist you in completing an action irl faster than rolling dice and doing the math yourself. 
Currently I have the random num generator somewhat working (although I would like to improve it)

This version is set to choose a random number between 1 and 20, I would like to figure out a way to have the program notice if you roll a 1 or a 20 (Crit hits / crit fail)

Also I need something later that will show me how to save certain values as variables,

```
@echo off
:Start
Set /a ans="%RANDOM% %% 20"+1
echo %ans%
pause
goto Start
```

(In regards to saving variables, when the program is ran, it will tell me that I am missing an operation.) 
The coloring portion was just for the hecks of it, if someone can show me a way to streamline that section please tell.
Please use lamens terms, Im still not very good at understanding any of this.

(CURRENT ASSIST PROGRAM PROGRESS)

```
@echo off 
cls
:BEGIN
Echo HI THERE! AND WELCOME TO MY GAME!! 
Echo Lets begin by setting your prefered color! 
:A
set choice=
set /p choice= RED, WHITE, OR BLUE?!? 
if not '%choice%'=='' set '%choice%'=='Red, White, Blue'
if '%choice%'=='RED' goto RED 
if '%choice%'=='WHITE' goto WHITE
if '%choice%'=='BLUE' goto BLUE
if '%choice%'=='Red' goto RED 
if '%choice%'=='White' goto WHITE
if '%choice%'=='Blue' goto BLUE
if '%choice%'=='red' goto RED 
if '%choice%'=='white' goto WHITE
if '%choice%'=='blue' goto BLUE
if '%choice%'=='9' goto 1Bs
echo "%choice%" is not a good color bro, do a different one
goto A
:RED
color 4
goto START SCREEN
:WHITE
color 7
goto START SCREEN
:BLUE
color 1
goto START SCREEN 
:START SCREEN
cls 
TITLE CHOOSER GAME BOI
Echo             ---THE DND GAME--- 
echo Welcome to the DND game, we will first choose your Attributes
echo Strength (How hard you hit) (STR)
echo Constitution (Your health) (CNST)
echo Knowledge (Better Rolls against Vendors and Questions) (KNLG)
echo Dexterity (Your chances of dodging and Hitting) (DXT)
echo You have a total of 10 points to apply to each Attribute
echo Your points HAVE to equal 10 otherwise you will have to restart 

:ATTRSET
set MXPNTS=10
set choice= 
set /p STR= STR (1-10) 
set choice= 
set /p CNST= CNST (1-10)
set CNST=CNST
set choice= 
set /p KNLG= KNLG (1-10) 
set KNLG=KNLG
set choice= 
set /p DXT= DXT (1-10)
set DXT=DXT

set /a ATTRTTL=STR+CNST+KNLG+DXT
echo ATTRTTL
if NOT ATTRTTL=MXPNTS goto ATTRSET
if ATTRTTL=MXPNTS goto testyay
pause
:testyay
pause
```

Comment: Where, specifically, are you encountering the error, and what, exactly is the error message you are getting. Also, is there any particular reason you're using batch, rather than vbscript, jscript, or PowerShell?

Comment: ---THE DND GAME---
Welcome to the DND game, we will first choose your Attributes
Strength (How hard you hit) (STR)
Constitution (Your health) (CNST)
Knowledge (Better Rolls aganist Vendors and Questions) (KNLG)
Dexterity (Your chances of dodging and Hitting) (DXT)
You have a total of 10 points to apply to each Attribute
Your points HAVE to equal 10 otherwise you will have to restart
STR (1-10) 1
CNST (1-10)2
KNLG (1-10) 3
DXT (1-10)4
Missing operand.
ECHO is off.
STR (1-10)

Comment: Also the reason I am using batch is because I don't think I have access to the other programming options, I am brand new at this and only know what I have researched so far. Sorry if this is just annoying ha.

Comment: You don't use percent symbols for variable assignment. You only use percent symbols when you need to use the value of a variable.  This is incorrect: `set /p %STR%= STR (1-10) `.

Comment: No idea why you are using double and single quotes in many of your `SET` commands.  They are not needed.

Comment: @Squashman I understand what your saying, but in this instance; since STR is being set to a values that I need to add up later (needs to equal 10), I need to use that value to add to the other values that all exist underneath the attributes (As this is just a test to see If I can even do it, nothing is permeant, and I can change anything you guys suggest) Thanks tho I will try it!

Comment: @Squashman And the reason I did that was because I was copying off of other sites. I have no knowledge behind coding whatsoever.

Comment: I find it very hard to believe you found a website that showed the batch file syntax you are using.

Comment: https://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntcolor.php , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263821/batch-files-third-if-not-statement-not-reached , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421441/batch-not-equal-inequality-operator These are a few of the things I have been looking at. I would like to restate that I do have NO previous understanding and so most likely started making mistakes.

Comment: I _strongly_ recommend that you find some good batch references; I tend to recommend [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt). What you are doing will require some rather sophisiticated techniques in batch; I would quite frankly recommend looking at other languages. The fact that you are using batch tells me that you are most likely on Windows; given that, you _do_ have access to jscript and vbscript, and if you are using Windows 7 or later, you also have access to PowerShell - and any of those three languages would really be better choices than batch.

Comment: Having said that, `set /a ATTRTTL=STR+CNST+KNLG+DXT` will not work; you will need to read and understand [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), and change this line to `set /a ATTRTTL=!STR!+!CNST!+!KNLG!+!DXT!`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, the code does not need delayed expansion

Comment: @Squashman - As near as I can tell, it does, because he's using values that are entered at execute time, not parse time.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin the `SET` commands are not inside a parentheses code block. That would be the only reason for the need to use delayed expansion. But even if the code was inside parentheses you do not need to use delayed expansion when using `SET /A`.

Comment: @VerbotenEmperor you do not need `set choice=` and `set CNST=CNST`.  You are actually sabotaging yourself.

Comment: Writing such script as a batch is a weirdest possible choice. Why don't use some more decent language?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally suggest:

```bat
@echo off
cls

:begin
echo HI THERE! AND WELCOME TO MY GAME!!
echo Lets begin by setting your preferred color!

:a
set /p choice= RED, WHITE, OR BLUE?!? 
if "%choice%" == "" (
    echo Please enter something!
    cls
    goto :A
)

for %%A IN (red white blue) do if /I "%choice%" == "%%A" (call :%%A & goto :start_screen)
if "%choice%" == "9" (goto 1Bs)
echo "%choice%" is not a good color bro, do a different one.
goto :a

:red
color 4
exit /b

:white
color 7
exit /b

:blue
color 1
exit /b

:start_screen
cls 
title CHOOSER GAME BOI
echo             ---THE DND GAME--- 
echo Welcome to the DND game, we will first choose your Attributes
echo Strength (How hard you hit) (STR)
echo Constitution (Your health) (CNST)
echo Knowledge (Better Rolls against Vendors and Questions) (KNLG)
echo Dexterity (Your chances of dodging and Hitting) (DXT)
echo You have a total of 10 points to apply to each Attribute
echo Your points HAVE to equal 10 otherwise you will have to restart 

:ATTRSET
set "mxpnts=10"
set /p "str=STR (1-10) "
set /p "cnst=CNST (1-10) "
set /p "knlg=KNLG (1-10) "
set /p "dxt=DXT (1-10) "

set /a "attrttl=str+cnst+knlg+dxt"
echo %ATTRTTL%
if not "%attrttl%" == "%mxpnts%" (goto :attrset) else (goto :testyay)
pause

:testyay
pause
```

- Capitalization detected! Successfully removed! As batch is a case *in*sensitive language, uppercase letters would make noise and make reader close the tab with your question and move on - or at least me.
- The whole thing about the `choice` variable you did was not needed. Just a `for` loop looping through the color words and checking (case insensitive) if the user input was `red`, `white` or `blue`.
- I have decided to `call` subroutines, not `goto` to them to save some lines - I usually do it to my programs: you had put 3 separate commands `goto START SCREEN` which could be simplified `call`ing the subroutine (which means `goto` to it, but then return) and then `goto` where you want.
- Remember: it is not good for your files/folders to contain a space in their name. This can cause quite many misbehaviours. It is just the same in all languages: when you name variables, functions, subroutines or whatever, **don't include spaces**! I have renamed it to `start_screen`.

That's all, follow excellent suggestions by Squashman in comments and read the help of some commands in cmd, typing `command /?` and you should be fine.

Comment: You are missing some exits in the code. If the user selects `RED`, the code will execute everything after `RED` before it returns and then goes back to the start_screen label and runs the code again.